# R handling column names in a for loop

Tags: r

I have a data frame that's ~ 50,000 X 200.  The column names are 4 different types with numbers on the end ranging from 1-50 (store1, price1, time1, rate1, store2, price2, time2, rate2,...,store50, price50, time50, rate50). I'm trying to create dummy variables depending on the values of each column but am having trouble getting R to handle the column names inside a loop.

```
store1    price1       time1      rate1     store2     price2    time2     rate2 ....
   A        55.55      08:09      1.44        B         44.44     11:09     1.46
   C        55.55      08:09      1.44        G         44.44     11:09     1.46
   X        55.55      08:09      1.44        E         44.44     11:09     1.46
   D        55.55      08:09      1.44        S         44.44     11:09     1.46
```

Here's what I have tried so far with no luck.

```
xform_data <- function(x) { 
       for(i in 1:50){
       storeX <-  (paste("store",i,sep="")) 
       storeX2  <- ifelse(storeX  == "A", 1, 2)
       x <- cbind(x, storeX2  )
       }
    x    
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following compares the name instead of the comparing the value:

```
ifelse(storeX  == "A", ...
```

Try:

```
ifelse(x[,storeX]  == "A", ...
```

Also, all the new columns will be called `storeX2`. You might prefer to rename them:

```
x <- cbind(x, storeX2)
colnames(x)[length(colnames(x))] <- storeX2
```

(I am sure there exist more elegant ways to do it.)

Comment: Thanks for the naming idea too.  That was gonna be my next question:)

Comment: @screechOwl: You're welcome. I'm glad my psychic powers are coming in handy ;-)

Answer (score 1):

@aix gave the proper way to do this with a loop, however you may find it quicker or easier to use some other tools, depending on what you want your final result to be.  Functions like `sapply` and `lapply` can be used to process every column of a data frame (or subset of a data frame) the same way.  The `model.matrix` function will convert variables into dummy variables (0's and 1's) in one step.  Other tools that may help include factors, `switch`, and `match`.